# reset chrome media engagement score

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5-video

I know that Chrome 66 introduced some restrictions when autoplaying a video (in HTML5). 
In some cases the autoplay is supported. One of the conditions to support autoplay is when the user has watched a video in the domain before or something similar.  So Chrome is keeping an internal score for each site. This score can be checked in chrome://media-engagement.

But now my problem is that for testing I have not figured it out a simple way to reset this score. So I can not properly test it for the new users.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I found to test using a clean score is to create a new profile in Chrome:

1- At the top right of Chrome, click the button with your name or People People.

2- Click Manage people.

3- Click Add person.

4- Click Save. A new window will open and ask you to sign in.

Comment: This also works when changing to "Guest" as the current user. `chrome://media-engagement` will then show an empty database.

Answer (score 6):

A quick throwaway solution to have a new window with empty MEI data is to open a "Guest window" by clicking the user avatar and choosing "Open Guest window" button.

[image: Chrome open guest window]

Comment: nice, did not know about this. notably incognito mode seems to share the settings with your normal login, but guest mode doesn't...

Answer (score 4):

It is not recommended to manually make changes to your profile folder, but this worked for me.

1. Go to `chrome://version/` and note the `Profile Path`
2. Close Chrome
3. Open the `Preferences` file in your profile folder with a text editor.
4. Delete the `media_engagement` entry.
5. Go to `chrome://media-engagement` to verify that everything has been cleared.

Alternatively you can just remove the `Preferences` file altogether but this removes a bunch of other things as well.

Comment: also this way you can add site to high score, nice

Answer (score 2):

You can also clean MEI by clearing browsing history:

- Click `Ctrl+Shift+Del` or navigate to `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`
- Go to `Advanced > All time`
- tick `Browsing history`
- Click `Clear data`
- Navigate to `chrome://media-engagement` to verify

[image: Chrome clear MEI data]

BTW. Note that notably going into incognito mode doesn't reset MEI; the MEI data are copied from regular session when opening first incognito tab (and then lives on its own until incognito session is closed).

Comment: that is good, but I did not want to clear my browser data, only reset the score

Comment: Would be great if I could reset browsing history only for the site for which I want to reset MEI.

Comment: You should be able to wipe a site from your history: • Open the History Page • Enter the domain of the site in the search box • Click the check-box for the first item • Hold `[⇧Shift]` • Click the check-box for the last item • Click `[Delete]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on scoring Media Engagement Index, you can run your chrome with a flag

```
--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required
```

Note that this flag may not be available in `chrome://flags`, full description [here](https://github.com/Hugo22O/chrome-autoplay). Alternatively, installing your app as PWA [should also work](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#media-engagement-index) (Chrome supports this on desktop, too).

Comment: Even though it's pretty much the exact opposite of what the OP wants, it's exactly what I want :) Thanks.